# How to get state obj by URL in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, state, angular-ui-router

Is the any way to get $state by URL?

```
app.controller('MyCtrlr', ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state) {
function getStateByUrl(URL) {
   ... //what should I do here?
   return stateObj;
}
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to get the name of the current state you can use

```
$state.current //whole object
```

and more specifically

```
$state.current.name //name of state
```

While this isn't getting it bythe  URL I'm hoping it might be what you want?

**Note:** the URL is also available in the object if you need it.

Comment: It is not actually what I need. Let's imagine we have url like:
http://localhost/login?redirect=room/123

Comment: $state.current is the current app state. But I do not need it. Lets imagine the active state name is 'dashboard'. There is the getStateByUrl() method in the state's controller. I need the call:

getStateByUrl('http://localhost/room/123')

returns a state which is configured like this:

    .state('room', {
       url: '/room/{id}',
       templateUrl: '/views/room.html',
       controller: 'RoomController'
     })

after that I'll probably perform transition to that state.